# Find g(Z) and show that is holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis

Let be $\gamma$ the circumference of the center at the origin and radius 2, and we will consider the function $g:\mathbb{C}/\gamma \to\mathbb{C}$

$g(z)=\displaystyle\int_{\gamma}\frac{cos(s)}{z-is}ds$

I have doubts about how to calculate $g(z)$ for $ \left |z\right|\ne2 $ and then show that it is holomorphic in $\mathbb{C}$\ {$z:\left |z\right|=2$} then calculate $g´(z)$

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: For $|z|<2$ the Cauchy integral formula gives $\int_{|s|=2}\frac{cos(s)}{s+iz}ds=2i\pi \ldots$. That it is analytic on $|z|<2$ is obvious because $1/(z-is),|s|=2$ is analytic for $|z|<2$. Same for $|z|>2$.

Comment: See Cauchy's differentiation formula: "Cauchy's integral formula - Wikipedia" https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula#Consequences

Answer (score 1):

Define $h(z)=g(iz)$.  Then $h$ is holomorphic with derivative $h'(z)=-1/(2\pi )\oint_{\gamma}\cos s/(z-s)^2\operatorname ds$, by Cauchy's differentiation formula.

But then $g'(z)=-ih'(-iz)$.

Meanwhile, for $|z|\gt2$, we have $g(z)=0$, by Cauchy's theorem.